# Ionic remove white blank space above keyboard

Tags: ios, ionic-framework

I am building an app using ionic framework. I got two issues.

1. I am getting a blank white space above keyboard.

[image]

2. White screen appears after splash screen and before app loading. I have tried the below mentioned code. But no use of it.

> ```
> <preference name="ShowSplashScreenSpinner" value="false" />
> <preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="false" />
> ```

How to avoid the white screen before app loading and how to avoid the blank space above the keyboard transition.

Thanks,
Raj.